# SQL: Need help listing all the unique names and the number of times they appear in two columns

Tags: sql

I've got 2 columns filled with names. The list is seemingly random and a person's name could show up in column A or column B (but never in both at the same instance). I want to write a query that will tell me all the names and the number of times each person is in either list. Here's an example of what I'm talking about

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | Cheryl |
| Andy | Tom |
| James | Mark |
| Tom | Ann |
| Cheryl | Jeff |
| Andy | Mark |

I'm looking for a query/function that will give me the list of names and the number of times they were seen in either column.

Any help is always appreciated!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table name is names and your columns are a,b then this should work:

```
select n.name, count(n.name)
from (
         select a as name from names
         union all
         select b as name from names
     ) n
group by n.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    Name,
    COUNT(1) as cnt
FROM (
    SELECT ColA As Name FROM my_table UNION ALL
    SELECT ColB As Name FROM my_table
) t
GROUP BY 
    Name
```

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tAzhJWrkQn5MLDap7i3aHW/0)

Comment: Ty ggordon!  I'm too sql stupid to know if this works right away but I'm digging in to give it a shot.  what does the "t" after the closed parenthesis do?

Comment: The `t` is syntax related. The subqueries used to create the table of all names requires a table alias, I have used `t` but you may use an ideal alias as you deem fit.

Comment: @paintrn Here is a live fiddle showing it how it works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tAzhJWrkQn5MLDap7i3aHW/0